# Git | Репозиторий на bitbucket.org

Tags: bitbucket, git, контроль-версий

Возникла проблема, нужно перекинуть проект с одного репозитория на другой и при этом не потерять все коммиты, ветки и т.д. До этого пушил по адресу https://bitbucket.org/my_name/name_project как можно перекинуть на другой адресс для пуша?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не умеете работать в консоли, тогда качайте:

[GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/)

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)

Добавляете проект, заходите в настройки и меняете путь, как показано на рисунке.
[image]

Если что-то не ясно - пишите.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает :)

Answer (score 3):

По идее достаточно просто создать новый пустой репозиторий и сделать пуш по его адресу. Другой вариант - сделать форк старого репозитория.

Есть еще один вариант - передать (transfer) репозиторий другому пользователю или в команду. Эта опция находится на странице администрирования репозитория ("шестеренка").

Answer (score 3):

У вас там одна ветка, `master`? Если одна, то достаточно:

```
git remote add new_origin git://....
git push new_origin master
```

Если веток больше, их все нужно будет пушнуть в new_origin по очереди.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то не получилось :(

Comment: @VladimirBabochin, что не получилось? Это верный способ.

Comment: @dzhioev: перечитайте принятый вопрос — наверняка тут можно предположить, что не получилось. =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да уж понял за 1.5 года

Comment: @dzhioev: там автор сам себе ответил с другого аккаунта и принял. Вы же это имеете в виду?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, не обратил внимания =) Это они после переезда на SO склеились?

Comment: @dzhioev: подозреваю, что второго мая это произошло. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14313/zarochintsev?tab=reputation

Comment: @NickVolynkin, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/332888/552 лол