# Стоит ли начинать писать на Apple Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Доброе время суток! В общем в скорем времени предстоит написать проект под iOS, по объемам не маленький, раньше сентября не выйдет, необходим от 6 iOS, вопрос вот в чём, есть ли смысл начинать реализовывать на Swift? Или же писать на старом, добром Objective-C? Что вы думаете по этому поводу? Интересно узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: Я бы писал на Свифте, как раз к осени они обещают всё зарелизить.

Comment: @ivanzoid

Вы сталкивались со Swift больше дня работы?

Comment: Не важно, Swift или что-то еще. 

Не стоит использовать в серьезных проектах для других людей технологии, которым еще не исполнилось 2-3 года.

 (поддержка превращается в кошмар и через пару лет невыносимо хочется все выбросить и переписать с начала).

Comment: @avp

> (поддержка превращается в кошмар и через пару лет невыносимо хочется все выбросить и переписать с начала).

Да, вы правы, с некоторыми проектами действительно порой так и происходит, особенно когда дописываешь чей-то проект, да и + ко всему в котором не придерживались элементарных стандартов. Но всё же, Apple показала миру Swift, до ещё и ко всему с гордостью заявила, что на нем приложения писать на много быстрее и проще, вот собственно и появился вопрос, стоит ли "тратить время".

Comment: @Bimawa

> Это потому - что она интелектуальная, а не тупая как в xcode. Но это тема для другого топика. Я на столько восхищен AppCode, что как тока появится время я напишу статью о окружении в котором я работаю.

Эту будет интересно почитать, статья будет на хабре?
(Пишу комментарий сюда, так как что-то не могу разобраться как откомментировать - пропала кнопка добавить комментарий, видимо я чего-то не понимаю)

Comment: Можете аргументировать ответ?

Comment: > Не важно, Swift или что-то еще.

Да ну как же, всё имеет свою важность!

> Не стоит использовать в серьезных проектах для других людей технологии...

Это вы о чём сейчас? Для каких других людей? Иноземных что ли?

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov, других -- значит не для себя 

(или своей команды (они всегда поймут, что хотел-то как лучше (а вот получилось...) и простят)).

Comment: @avp

Извините, но я не понимаю о чём вы говорите

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov, я говорю о том, что *не маленькие проекты*, которые еще и быстро (до сентября?) надо сделать (из слов автора) **не стоит начинать, используя не устоявшиеся технологии**.

Конечно, тут все зависит от того, кто какой смысл (планируемый объем кода, размер команды разработчиков, предполагаемая прибыль и возможные издержки (штрафные санкции)) вкладывает в слова "проект" и "не маленький".

Comment: > я говорю о том, что не маленькие проекты, которые еще и быстро (до сентября?) надо сделать (из слов автора)

Автор как раз таки указал:

> по объемам не маленький, раньше сентября не выйдет

Answer (score 6):

Apple Swift не поддерживает платформы ниже Mac OS X 10.9, iOS 7.0. К тому же до тех пор пока не будет стабильной версии Xcode 6 вы не сможете задеплоить в аппстор Ваше приложение (что произойдет вероятно осенью, после следующего Apple-ивента).

Comment: >Apple Swift не поддерживает платформы ниже Mac OS X 10.9, iOS 7.0.

Странно, в Xcode 6 Beta 2 приложение на Swift отлично запускается на iOS6

Comment: Так было сказано на WWDC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower хотя тут люди говорят то можно и ниже запускать. В любом случае язык и среда еще более чем сырые. Если до осени не дадут нам Xcode 6 - это станет преградой

Comment: @AlexThumb

Не могу не согласиться с Вами! У вас случайно нет информации, приложения на Objective-C можно будет отправить в AppStore для iOS8?

Comment: @Ковальский, разумеется, objc еще никто не отменял. Судя по усердию Apple, процесс перехода на Swift неизбежен. Но он будет длиться еще 2-3 года в течении которых objc все еще будет играть большую роль при разработке приложений

Comment: Поддерживаю @AlexThumb  swift на столько сырой, циклы работают в 5 раз медленней JS и не только циклы. Использую Swift повседневно.. читанием документации о нем в метро.

Comment: @Bimawa

> Использую Swift повседневно.. читанием документации о нем в метро.

Тяжело ли перейти на Swift после Objective-C?

Comment: Если до objective-c есть опыт разработки в любых других языках, то нет. Так как swift это агрегатор всех языков в одном, тут что-то из Делфи, очень много из ECMA, Урааа Кортежи есть, Функциональщинаа чуть чуть. В целом очень мощный язык будет. Разве что из Ruby ни чего не взяли, наверное кишка не выдержала. Он очень гибкий получился, теперь его можно сравнить с С#, но все равно не то... Но точно могу сказать что я лучше на нем буду писать чем на Obj-c, если решат проблему с производительностью и будет полная поддержка языка в AppCode. :D

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/227243/ Модификаторов доступа нет еще ;)  Тоесть язык на столько сырой, что я пока читаю фантастичкескую книгу под названием "Swift"

Comment: @Bimawa

Я Swift потыкал чуть больше суток, мне тоже язык понравился, но уж больно был непривычный синтаксис (сильно тупил первые часы), но синтаксис после Obj-C всё равно не привычный (привык вместо "=" писать "set", и не "cell.textLabel.text = @"text";, a [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Text"];")

Comment: @Bimawa

> Но точно могу сказать что я лучше на нем буду писать чем на Obj-c, если решат проблему с производительностью и будет полная поддержка языка в AppCode. :D

Пробовал AppCode, как-то не понравилась среда, уж эта, несчастная 1 секунда - которая уходит на то, что бы AppCode предложил мне автодописание как-то меня раздражала и заставляла меня нервничать :D

Comment: >мне тоже язык понравился, но уж больно был непривычный синтаксис (сильно тупил первые часы)

Да это как перейти с С на JS и офигивать что вместо типа нужно писать var.
Но это намного менее болезненно чем с JS переходить на Assembler. ^_^

Comment: >AppCode предложил мне автодописание как-то меня раздражала и заставляла меня нервничать

Это потому - что она интелектуальная, а не тупая как в xcode. Но это тема для другого топика. Я на столько восхищен AppCode, что как тока появится время я напишу статью о окружении в котором я работаю.

Comment: > Это потому - что она интелектуальная, а не тупая как в xcode. Но это тема для другого топика. Я на столько восхищен AppCode, что как тока появится время я напишу статью о окружении в котором я работаю.

@Bimawa будет интересно почитать о окружении в котором вы работаете, и почему Xcode плохо влияет на людей :)

Answer (score 5):

Я сейчас пишу на **Swift** огромный проект (Аэрофлот iPad) и все ок, бывают небольшие проблемы с самим xCode (автокомплит отваливается постоянно, сама IDE крешится время от времени, возникают совершенно идиотские проблемы) и несколько функций языка еще недоделаны (например, override var) да и пока нельзя засабмитить проект в стор, но к осени все должно быть. 
На самом деле, Swift здорово сокращает время разработки такими вещами, как мощные конструкции switch, pattern matching, associated values в enums и многое другое.

все это дело отлично дружит с Objective-C классами и категориями и одном проекте

**Разрабатываю на Swift fulltime недели 3, полет нормальный!**

Коротко опишу ситуацию:
Проект был под iPhone на Objective-C, сейчас iPhone практически готов, сделали из проекта universal, добавили сториборд для iPad. Само-собой модель данных, сервер-клиент взаимодействие и некоторая логика вынесены и готовы для iPhone проекта в Objective-C. Все, что делается под iPad - делается на Swift, при этом используюется огромное количество классов, написанных ранее на Objective-C. Иногда, значительно реже, в Objective-C используются классы или категории, написанные на Swift. С этим проблем не выявил.
Пока самая большая проблема - xCode 6, он реально глючит, в остальном работать можно даже с реально большими проектами, самое главное, смотрите, чтобы ваш дедлайн не стоял раньше сентября, иначе не залиться в App Store! В остальном - настоятельно рекомендую к изучению и использованию и говорю это как человек, разрабатывающий на Objective-C уже более 3.5 лет!

**По поводу доступа к Swift классам из Objective-C:**

во-первых, все классы (или протоколы), доступ к которым будет нужен, должны начинаться с ключевого слова **@objc**, например:

```
@objc class MyClass : NSObject /* or any NSObject subclass */ { }
@objc protocol MyProtocol { }
```

во-вторых, в документации не точно указано, если у вас **только один дефалтовый модуль**, то есть вы **НЕ создавали** отдельно других, вам нужно импортить только **MyProject-Swift.h**

то есть просто в нужном месте пишем:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

**далее мне доступны все классы и протоколы, написанные на Swift с пометкой @objc
Никаких дополнительных настроек в проекте выставлять не потребовалось, проект изначально был создан в xCode 5.1**, думаю, что проекты, созданные в xCode 6 Beta не должны и подавно требовать дополнительных настроек, хотя не проверял...
Надеюсь, это поможет, а то в комментах много вопросов на эту тему, всем удачи!

Comment: @iFreeman

Для каких версий iOS Вы пишете проект?

В интернете много постов, о том, что приложения на Swift будут работать с 7 iOS

Comment: @iFreeman капец ты рисковый парень, с железными нервами... Я раз 10 уронил xCode и психанул.

Comment: ну да, на самом деле есть проблемы со стабильностью в новом xCode, но пока все проблемы решаемы. Приложение под iOS 7+ все работает на девайсах от 7.0 до 8 beta, правда есть некоторые незначительные различия в поведении на разных версиях iOS, я так понял это пока баг языка, будем смотреть потом уже на нормальной версии iOS 8 SDK

Comment: @iFreeman

Кстати, есть возможность с кода на Objective-C обратиться к коду на Swift?

Comment: да конечно, работает отлично в обе стороны!

Comment: @iFreeman

С кода на Swift обратиться к Objective-C я разобрался (достаточно импортировать неоходимые файлы в <project-name-Bridging-Header.h>), а как быть, если наоборот? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Берем swift файл, например MyBeautifulSwiftModule.swift и импортим его как #import "MyBeautifulSwiftModule-swift.h" - и все, можно работать!

Comment: @iFreeman

Странно, всё сделал как вы написали, но Xcode 6 Beta 2 всё равно не дает (не видит) код написанный на Swift с Objective-C, но спасибо Вам за подсказку!

Comment: > Странно, всё сделал как вы написали, но Xcode 6 Beta 2 всё равно не дает (не видит) код написанный на Swift с Objective-C, но спасибо Вам за подсказку!

Наблюдаю у себя такую же проблема (
Но методы написанные на Objective-C нормально вызвать можно

Comment: > Берем swift файл, например MyBeautifulSwiftModule.swift и импортим его как #import "MyBeautifulSwiftModule-swift.h" - и все, можно работать!

Эго же нужно импортировать в:

> <project_name-Bridging-Header.h>)
?

Comment: В общем куда я бы их не импортировал, Xcode не дает вызвать код написанный на Swift из Objective-C, @iFreeman, подскажите, в чём загвоздка? Сырой Xcode?

Comment: @Ковальский, @dev_nikita_ysacov добавил в ответ по поводу доступа к Swift из Objective-C, попробуйте, надеюсь, поможет!

Answer (score 3):

В общем, поработав на чистом Swift'e - в целях обучения на небольшом проекте - могу сказать, что язык понравился, за исключением некоторых вещей. Например вместо **set** теперь **=**, вместо **[]** теперь **.** - мелочи, но уж до боли не привычно как-то всё, потом удивило, назначить на кнопку **Action** - теперь строкой писать нужно - из-за этого возникили у меня проблемы, так как компилятор её не проверяет, а я почему-то не подумал туда сразу посмотреть, но у языка есть будущее :)

Но я думаю, что чтоит начинать писать на Swift'e, так как в будущем его Apple ещё дальше пропехнёт, вопрос только когда вы потратите время на "обучение", сейчас или через некоторое время, поддерживаемые версии по заявлеием от 7, но у меня и на 6 работает (возможно временно).

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov

Ваше приложение стабильно работает? Проводили тесты в **Instruments**?

Comment: @Ковальский

Оно у меня простое как 2 копейти, я его не тестил

Comment: @Ковальский, но работает нормально :)

Answer (score -1):

Swift типа официально вышел. Мне хватило нескольких видеоуроков для знакомства со ним.

Раньше мне просто не нравился его синтаксис, теперь я обнаружил я одну вещь, которая может превратить абсолютно любой проект в АД.

Я имею в виду ПОЛНОЕ ОТСУТСТВИЕ неявного приведения типов, которое касается не только классов.

Простой пример - объявите 2 переменные: целочисленную и дробную - и попробуйте их сложить. НИЧЕГО НЕ ПОЛУЧИТСЯ без приведения целого числа к дробному. А теперь представьте, сколько формул может быть в проекте. Да вы повеситесь каждую переменную переводить в дробный тип

Comment: > Да вы повеситесь каждую переменную переводить в дробный тип  

Если вам нужно работать с дробными числами, то зачем хранить их как целые?  
Ну и в сторону generic’ов можно посмотреть.

Comment: Вы еще вставки из objective-c предложите использовать. Нужно например обратиться к элементу массива? дробной переменной будете указывать? А остаток от деления или деление нацело - тоже дробными будете делать?

и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Вот я как джавист смотрю на эти возмущения и мне так смешно)